# How to define the motion path of one object on a surface of the other one?

Tags: java, c++, collision-detection, simulation, physics

I have an uncommon problem. There are 2 3D objects, which are represented by arrays of vertices and triangles (.stl files). Each of them contains a big enough amount of vertices: 1-10 mln ones. The surfaces of these models are rough, and can contain different spikes or hollows.

The aim is to determine path of one these objects, when it moves with contact on the surface of the other one. Moreover, the algorithm should consider how many degrees of freedom are available. In every case there are only 2 objects and one of them is fixed.

Example, object `M1` moves on a surface of object `M2`, which is fixed. It's necessary to move M1 from point `A` to `B`. For M1 it's also available one more degree of freedom - along the axis (let's call it `AC`) perpendicular to `AB`. So, the path can be only the curve in the plane `(AC, AB)`. But due to this path, during the motion `M1` should always has at least one contact point.

I tried to perform it with collision detection algorithm, but it seems it will be very complicated calculations for ordinary computers. Can anybody advise some algorithms, libraries or concepts how to perform this idea? 
P.S. I use C, C++ and Java.

Comment: You should look into [OpenRAVE](http://openrave.org/) or [Open Motion Planning Library](http://ompl.kavrakilab.org/). This is a motion planning problem. Collision checking is only a small portion of your problem.

Comment: You should be more explicit about what you are trying to do exactly. There are many unanswered questions in the way you abstracted the question which may significantly simplify the answer. What are these objects you are talking about? What kind of constraint their geometry have?

Comment: @JarkkoL I need to describe the interraction of the upper and lower dentures, considering the geometry of each tooth and articulation movements of the mandible. I have .stl files of each denture and possible articulation movements.

Comment: @Eugene In that case sounds like you should be able to define the dentures as heightmaps for the movement simulation, which simplifies the problem significantly.

Comment: @JarkkoL Hmm... It's an idea... Thanks!